# How to interpret similarity scores using RWMD in text2vec?

Tags: text2vec

How do I interpret the similarity scores that are computed from the relaxed word mover's distance function in text2vec?

```
rwmd_model = RelaxedwordMoversDistance$new(dtm, wv)
rwms = rwmd_model$sim2
head(sort(rmws[1,], decreasing = T)
... 0.595
... 0.594
... 0.585
... 0.573
```

Is 0.595 a high degree of similarity? Is similarity bounded at 0,1? Thanks!

I am looking for help interpreting these scores. The code works just fine.